# how make active jQuery Accordion Menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have jQuery simple vertical accordion menu.

Javascript:

```js
$(document).ready(function () { 
  $('#nav > li > a').click(function(){
    if ($(this).attr('class') != 'active'){
      $('#nav li ul').slideUp();
      $(this).next().slideToggle();
      $('#nav li a').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
    } else {
      $('#nav li ul').slideUp();
      $('#nav li a').removeClass('active');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#nav li ul {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="nav">
  <li><a href="#">Item 1</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 1 a</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 1 b</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 1 c</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 2</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 2 a</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 2 b</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 3</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 2 a</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 2 b</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 4</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 2 a</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 2 b</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

i want have class showmenu  , and if  i add this class for  "Item 3"  this menu will be open automatically when page load. how can do this

Comment: Please insert it into a code snippet for us to run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `slideDown()` to the `ul` which is inside `li` with **showmenu** class

```
 $('.showmenu ul').slideDown();
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () { 
  $('.showmenu ul').slideDown();
  $('#nav > li > a').click(function(){
    if ($(this).attr('class') != 'active'){
      $('#nav li ul').slideUp();
      $(this).next().slideToggle();
      $('#nav li a').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
    } else {
      $('#nav li ul').slideUp();
      $('#nav li a').removeClass('active');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#nav li ul {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="nav">
      <li><a href="#">Item 1</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 1 a</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 1 b</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 1 c</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 2</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 2 a</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 2 b</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="showmenu"><a href="#">Item 3</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 2 a</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 2 b</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 4</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 2 a</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 2 b</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: yeah mine dak yelzam